# Waves, matter displacement

Tags: waves

When a wave travels through matter, the matter's particles return to their equilibrium position once the wave is passed, is that statement correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding the displacement of a particle in a wave](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109542/understanding-the-displacement-of-a-particle-in-a-wave)

Comment: What sort of wave? A gravitational wave, a vibrational wave or a wave on water. Also what medium? A perfectly elastic one or one with dissipation?

Comment: @JohnRenie, for now i'm just trying to understand the concept of wave. If it depends on the parameters you listed, can you explain it?

Comment: This statement is not correct in full generality. There are many cases where it is valid, but usually not unconditionally (a string **without dispersion**, ideal linear acoustic medium with zero mean flow, etc. etc.). I would recommend you to study a bit more and then ask more specific question. Start e.g. with keywords: dispersion, surface wave, burgers equation...

Comment: Yes and no. For waves on a lake, each particle travels in circles. For waves on a stream, the particles also move downstream.